# How to write a function that prints output in one line?

Tags: r

How to write a function that prints output in one line? Like this:

```
> x<-c(1,2,3,4)
> f(x)
[1] mean=2.5 sd=1.290994
```

I use R from an application written in another language, I need to calculated values ​​are in the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write a function, it already exists in R, it's called `c`

```
> c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
    mean       sd 
2.500000 1.290994
```

`cat` is another alternative if you want the result in one line

```
> cat("mean =", mean(x), "sd =", sd(x))
mean = 2.5 sd = 1.290994
```

Comment: `c` is short for *Combine*

Comment: i need one line output, you have two

Comment: @Jilber thank you, bat cat does not insert a new line, need `cat("mean =", mean(x), "sd =", sd(x), "\n")`